# How to handle leap years when using groupby.shift in Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame with the following structure:

[image]

What I am trying to do is for each **[location, date]** to have not only the current amount but also the amount from one year ago (**NOT** 365 days). What I am struggling with here is the leap year handling (For example, 2020). If I had to find the value for 29th of Feb, 2020, it would be 1st of March, 2021.

My main approach goes around **groupby.shift**

```
data[f"1_year_ago_amnt"] = (
        data.sort_values("date")
        .groupby("location")["amount"]
        .shift(??365 or 366??)
    )
```

I've been trying to add some metadata to the data frame related to the fact if current year is a leap one or not

[image]

and then have two additional columns (365 days back and 366 days back). But I am not sure this is the right approach. It really depends if current day is before 29th of Feb or after that. I believe there's a more elegant straight-forward way.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

One trick (both in Pandas and other tabular frameworks supporting `groupby`) is to group by not only the location column but also the portions of the date that you want to keep in tact. In this case you want to keep the month and day fixed while moving one year backward. This can be accomplished for your DataFrame with something like the following:

```py
(data.sort_values('date')
     .groupby([
         data.location,
         data.date.dt.month,
         data.date.dt.day
     ])
     .amount
     .shift(1))
```

## Diving Deeper

For more complex problems involving variable-length date and time offsets (years, "four business days from now", etc.), Pandas has built-in [timeseries offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html) that can usually be used alongside `groupby`, `apply`, etc. to accomplish your goals.

For example, you can use a [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) to make adding years (regardless of whether or not they're leap years) easy.

```py
import pandas as pd

timestamp = pd.Timestamp('2019-03-01 01:02:03')

# Right
print(
    'Date + DateOffset(years=1):',
    timestamp + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
)

# Wrong
print(
    'Date + DateOffset:',
    timestamp + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=365)
)
```

The first of the print statements will output `2020-03-01 09:10:11`, which is correct, since 2020 is a leap year.
On the other hand, the second matches what you've tried with `groupby(…).shift`, printing `2020-02-29 09:10:11`.